# How to find a linked file in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-impress

My system died several months ago.  I had enough warning to back up the hard drive, though.  Now I'm digging through the backup trying to pull out a few files.  One of them is an old OpenOffice Impress presentation.  I can open it and it mostly works, except for one slide that used to have a video clip on it.  Now it's just a big gray box with a question mark.

I can't find the linked video clip in the backup.  Problem is, I can't find its location and filename from OpenOffice either.  I did what any experienced Windows user would do, right-clicked on it and went to Properties to get the linked path... but there's no Properties in the context menu, and none of the stuff in the context menu actually helps.  The information has to be there somewhere so OO knows where to find it.  How do I access it?  It's gotta be something simple that I'm just overlooking, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The impress file is a zip file with a different extension. Rename the .odp file to .zip, use a zip utility to open the content.xml file contained therein and search the content file for video file extensions. In a test I did, I found the video file link in a `<draw:plugin xlink:href="path/name.avi" ....</draw>` xml element.

Comment: OK, that worked.  Though it really shouldn't be that... manual.  There should be some way to get the information from within Impress.  I find myself rather "unimpressed."